# Is stroboscope a substitution for accelerometer testing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

given that handy stroboscope can also check translational vibration of parts, is it a substitute for a test that can be done by accelerometer for stationary vibrating equipment?

Comment: This is pretty much a repeat of your previous question, https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40018/is-stroboscope-a-useful-device-to-control-the-translational-vibrations. If you don't get an answer to a question then please improve it rather than post it again.

Comment: No it's not a repeat, that was with focus on vibration type here the instrumentation is the focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Strobes are useful for what they can do, but they are not substitutes for accelerometers.

A strobe can give you a "picture", but it doesn't *measure* anything except maybe frequency. It doesn't measure amplitude, harmonic content of the vibration, etc.

Also a strobe is only useful for amplitudes which are big enough to see. Accelerometers can measure high frequency vibrations with amplitudes of micrometers or smaller.